# Using AJAX to call PHP file to return database results via JSON and populate a selection box

Tags: php, ajax, json, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am currently a student so please realize my skills are very new (only a couple of months literally for all of HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP, etc). I am working on a school project for a PHP class and some of what I want to do it outside the scope of what I have learned thus far (JSON and AJAX are entirely new to me). This will be my first post on this site although I have used it for reference quite often in the last couple of months.

My goal is to make a website where a drop box (selection box) it populated with car manufacturers from a MySQLi database table called "make". Once you select a car "make" then the second drop box should become enabled and populate with *only* the relevant models for the selected manufacturer. This model information comes from another table on the same database called "model".

The "make" table is structured as such:

INSERT INTO `make` (`id`, `code`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'ACURA', 'Acura'),
(2, 'ALFA', 'Alfa Romeo'),
(3, 'AMC', 'AMC'),
(4, 'ASTON', 'Aston Martin'),
(5, 'AUDI', 'Audi'),
(6, 'AVANTI', 'Avanti'),
(7, 'BENTL', 'Bentley'),
(8, 'BMW', 'BMW'),
(9, 'BUICK', 'Buick'),
(10, 'CAD', 'Cadillac'),
(11, 'CHEV', 'Chevrolet'),
(12, 'CHRY', 'Chrysler'),
(13, 'DAEW', 'Daewoo'),
etc

The "model" table looks like this:

INSERT INTO `model` (`id`, `make_id`, `code`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'CL_MODELS', 'CL Models (4)'),
(2, 1, '2.2CL', ' - 2.2CL'),
(3, 1, '2.3CL', ' - 2.3CL'),
(4, 1, '3.0CL', ' - 3.0CL'),
(5, 1, '3.2CL', ' - 3.2CL'),
(6, 1, 'ILX', 'ILX'),
(7, 1, 'INTEG', 'Integra'),
(8, 1, 'LEGEND', 'Legend'),
(9, 1, 'MDX', 'MDX'),
(10, 1, 'NSX', 'NSX'),
(11, 1, 'RDX', 'RDX'),
(12, 1, 'RL_MODELS', 'RL Models (2)'),
(13, 1, '3.5RL', ' - 3.5 RL'),
(14, 1, 'RL', ' - RL'),
(15, 1, 'RSX', 'RSX'),
(16, 1, 'SLX', 'SLX'),
(17, 1, 'TL_MODELS', 'TL Models (3)'),
etc

I have the code populating the first dropbox from the database table "make" just fine. Once you select a make from the dropbox (onchange event) it seems to be calling my javascript function ok as I can alert the make and it shows up ok. After that it doesn't work. I am not sure if it's calling my php code properly, if the php is working right etc. Please review and let me know what you think!

Here is my HTML & Javascript function for the two dropboxes:

```js
<script>
function getModel(carMake)
{
  var xmlhttp;
  var getRequest;
  alert(carMake); //This alert is working and shows car make!
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
   var carModels = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).split(' ');
   alert (carModels.toString());
   var carModelsHTML = "";
   for (i=0; i < carModels.length; i++)
   {
  carModelsHTML += "<option value=\"" + carModel[i] + "\">" + carModel[i] + "</option><br/>";
   }
   alert(carModelsHTML);
   document.getElementById("vehicle_model").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("AjaxDiv").innerHTML = carModelsHTML;
    }
  }
  
getRequest = "myAjax.php?make="+carMake;
xmlhttp.open("GET",getRequest,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

```html
Vehicle Make:

<select name="vehicle_make" value="<? echo $_SESSION['vehicle_make']?>" required onchange="getModel(this.value)">
<?
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM make"; // Build an MySQLi statement to select the makes of all MFGs
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); // Perform the MySQLi query on the database to get the filename.
      
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) //while we haven't the end of the list of MFGs
 {
 ?>
      <option value="<? echo $row["title"] ?>"><? echo $row["title"] ?></option>
    <?
 }

     
?>
</select>

<br/>

Vehicle Model:

<select name="vehicle_model" value="<? echo $_SESSION['vehicle_model']?>" required disabled>
 <div id="ajaxDiv">
     <!-- Javascript placeholder for getModel function -->
 </div>
</select>
```

Here is my PHP file - I wasn't sure if I needed to include my database connection file again, I assumed not but tried it when the code wasn't working.

```html
<?
include "database.php";

$value = $_REQUEST["make"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM make WHERE title=" . $value; // Build an MySQLi statement to select the corresponding make of car
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); // Perform the MySQLi query on the database
$makeID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM model WHERE id=" . $makeID["id"]; //Now cross reference the models of car for that manufacturer using the corresponding id from the "make" table.
$result = array(); //Reset the $result array to be reused.
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); //Perform the data collection from the model table of the database

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 $models = $row["title"] . " ";
}
trim($models); //The last entry will have an extra space on the end, in order not to create encoding issues we will trim it off.
$data = json_encode(array("models" => $models)); //Encode all the models from the string we created into an object so we can send it back to the javascipt on the client side.
echo $data; //By echoing out the object at the end we are passing the encoded data back to the javascript on the other side.

?>
```

Comment: You really need to narrow the question down. Giant walls of code make it much less likely someone's going to be able to help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I have a habit of being a bit detailed and long winded. Unfortunately, not knowing where the problem is and being stuck after trying the limited debugging I know has led me here to post all relevant code and try to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you to look into this first:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

I think you will get quite far with it an learn much more.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have been here already. I have gone through the w3schools "lessons" on ajax from start to finish and most of the php already as well. I have also searched on this site for a solution and have gathered up what bits and pieces of relevant code I could. Again, I am a beginner but have googled as much as I can. I am just looking for someone to quickly review my code and point me in the right direction as to WHERE the problem is. I will go from there.

Comment: To debug the hole thing I would recommend to start with the server side. Put a few debugging outputs into your php code an call the php page directly with adding GET data as needed to the url. So all debugging will be printed directly to the browser window.

Comment: For example echo the $makeid and each $row of course with a whitespace. And maybe the $data at the end. Then call yourphpfile.php?make=anyid in your browserwindow

Comment: That's an excellent idea. I will try that. Thanks for the suggestion. My brain is so full of new information from searches etc. I know that I am missing some of the obvious stuff... which is exactly why I came here! :)

Answer (score 0):

With the debugging idea provided by Jonathan I was able to make some progress and finally got it working. Note there are quite a few changes done to the code from original post but hopefully this will help others that might get stuck on similar problems or come by this post...

Here is the Javascript and HTML now:

```js
<script>
function getModel(carMake)
{
var xmlhttp;
var getRequest;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
  var carModels = xmlhttp.responseText.split(','); //Receive the car models in one long string with each seperated by a ',' and split it up into an array
  
  //Below section of code grabs the current "model" dropbox and finds the length, then nulls all options.
  var currentOptions = document.getElementById("vehicle_model");
  for (i = currentOptions.options.length-1; i >=0; i--)
  {
   currentOptions.remove(i);
  }
  
  //Below goes through all the model options just returned from the database and populates the "model" dropbox again.
  for (i=0; i < carModels.length; i++)
  {
   var newOption = document.createElement("option");
   newOption.text = carModels[i];
   newOption.value = carModels[i];
   var dropDown = document.getElementById("vehicle_model");
   try
    {
     dropDown.add(newOption, null); //This is for all browsers except old IE
    }
    catch(ex) //If an exception occurs and the option refuses to add then try IE option below
    {
     dropDown.add(newOption); //For older versions of IE
    }
  }
    }
  }
getRequest = "myAjax.php?make="+carMake;
xmlhttp.open("GET",getRequest,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

```html
Vehicle Make:

<select id="vehicle_make" value="<? echo $_SESSION['vehicle_make']?>" required onchange="getModel(this.value)">
<?
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM make"; // Build an MySQLi statement to select all MFGs in database
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); // Perform the MySQLi query on the database.
      
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
?>
        <option value="<? echo $row["title"] ?>"><? echo $row["title"] ?></option>
      <?
    }
      ?>
</select>
<br/>

Vehicle Model:

<select id="vehicle_model" value="<? echo $_SESSION['vehicle_model']?>" required>
</select>
```

Then here is the PHP code:

```html
<?
include "database.php"; //connects to the MySQLi database - $mysqli
$value = $_REQUEST["make"];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM make WHERE title='" . $value . "'"; // Build an MySQLi statement to select the filename from the users table using the ID for reference.
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); // Perform the MySQLi query on the database to get the filename.
$makeID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // Put data gathered into $makeID


$sql = "SELECT * FROM model WHERE make_id=" . $makeID["id"]; //Now cross reference the models of car for that manufacturer using the corresponding id from the make table.

$result = array(); //Reset the $result array to be reused.
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); //Perform the data collection from the model table of the database

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) //For each model found this will build one string into $models with each seperated by a ','
{
 $models = $models . $row["title"] . ",";
}

$models = trim($models, ","); //The last entry will have an extra ',' on the end, to avoid future issues we will trim it off.

echo $models; //By echoing out the string we are passing it back to the javascript

?>
```

And that did it! Thanks for the debugging lesson. That's all I needed to get me moving in the right direction.